# Short term, Long term and medium term schedulers

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, jobs, job-scheduling

What are the scheduling algorithms(FCFS,SJF,SRTF,LRTF,RR e.t.c) used by short term, medium term and long term schedulers respectively ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between short term, medium term and long term scheduler is entirely the creation of operating systems textbooks to confuse CS students. Most operating systems have A scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm for all 3 schedulers depends upon implementation. But Generally, all 3 schedulers use the combination of FCFS, Round Robin and Priority scheduling algorithm. SJF, SRTF, and LRTF are used less because it is impossible to predict the burst of any process.
For more information, you can read about Multilevel queue scheduling.